# Is "I have no much time." correct?

Tags: negation, determiners, quantifiers

I know "I have no time." is correct.

> I have no much time.

But as to "I have no much time." to mean "not enough time",
the sentence seems to have self-contradiction in a sense.

Is the sentence correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any actual grammatical rule as to why ***I have no much time*** isn't "valid", but it definitely *isn't* acceptable.

Comment: You could say "I have not much time," but it would be unusual. "I have little time" is colloquial.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep, there is :-)

Comment: I have no time = I do not have any time. I have no money - I don't have any money. Either you use /no/ or you put the verb in the negative and use any. They both mean exactly the same thing. If you add MUCH, you cannot use no. I don't have much time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I always appreciate your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @snailplane♦: If there is indeed a relevant "rule", what exactly is it? I just found [this from 1830:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+no+much+appetite+for%22) *I take coffee or tea w' toast, a fresh egg or a bit o' salmon, though I have **no much appetite** for breakfast.* I admit that sounds "archaic", but consider [*I helped myself to a portion of the smoking round, and commenced eating **with no little appetite**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+no+little+appetite%22) That I think is just "dated / literary" (i.e. - it's about style/idiomacy, not grammar).

Comment: /No much appetite/ there sounds like a regional or class dialect. Why is it relevant to cite usage from the 1800s? Why not all the way back to Elizabethan English?  What about the variant: ain't got much, while we are at it. There is a difference between an ELL explanations and a full Monty showing of variations. Why not turn what is a simple matter into a full-blown academic discussion with all the bells and whistles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

"no much" is never correct, instead use "not much."

> That is not much time.
>   Not much later, he left.

When using 'not', in general move the negative to before the verb:

> I went not very far. (awkward) -->
>   I did not go very far. (correct)

So, the solution:

> I have no much time. (wrong) -->
>   I have not much time. (awkward) -->
>   I do not have much time. (correct)
>   I don't have much time. (correct)

Comment: I have not much time is not grammatical in English at all.

Comment: @Lambie -- I strongly agree that it is not *colloquial*. That does not mean it isn't *grammatical*. "I haven't much" is actually still widely used -- I haven't much to say, I haven't much to offer, I haven't much time left. "I have not much" is just an uncontracted form of this grammatically correct (if awkward and archaic) phrasing.

Comment: JeremyDouglass Really? There is any argument here?? "I haven't much money, time or patience", of course. But ***not***: I have not much money is simply not heard. What one actually ***hears*** is: I have ***little*** money; I've not got much money (often heard in British English but also other Englishes) and I don't have much money.

Comment: So glad we agree on both what is common usage and that the correct answers given here are correct!

Comment: Isn't there any possibility to regard "I have not much time." as "I have {not much time}." instead of "I {have not} much time."? It seems like there is a debate whether "have not" form is grammatical or not. If instead we regard that sentence in a sense considering "not much" in relation with "time" rather than the verb "have", there can be no problem in my thought. But, I am not a good English speaker so I am not sure. :)

Comment: /have not/ is grammatical. For example: He has not a whit of sense. The rub is in the much. [Ay, there's the rub (clue for ELLers)]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the confirmation. But isn't it on the debate whether /have not/ is grammatical or not? Can't we look at the sentence in a way like "* I + have + not much time.*" instead of "*I + have not + much time.*"?

Comment: @Smart Humanism No, "there is no debate" as far as I'm concerned. The two readings you have made make no difference. The addition of the word much is not idiomatic with either one. One would actually say: I + have + little+ time. You have "made me" repeat myself: I + have + a lot/lots of+ time versus I + have+ little + time.